# How to setup the below solar configurations?

Tags: solar-power

I have following components :-

– 2 * 250 watt solar panels v-guard

– 1 * 12 volt, 150ah battery mtekpower

– 1 * 900va inverter v-guard

– 1 * 12/24 volt , 50amp charge controller v-guard

the connection wire length is about 4 metres.

I have connected the solar panels in parallel. but the charge controller showing the error message "High PV Voltage Shutdown" . and no longer supplying charge to battery.Is there any problem in connection or any component needs to be added ? how to make this setup works ?

Comment: Maybe a better fit for diy stackexchange.

Comment: I don't know if this question is specifically off-topic here, but it would almost certainly do better on diy or electronics.